Axisymmetric jet boundary conditions
I am working on analyzing a flow downstream of an axisymmetric jet in a 2D slice i.e, in a rectangle (size L,R) of (z,r) coordinates so that velocity components are (w,v). I am confused about the boundary conditions at left edge and symmetric boundary and their physical meaning.
At the left edge of the rectangle, inflow velocity w_in can be defined for a height 0<r<h<<R representing the outflow from the jet. The w_in should can be a symmetric profile between 0<r<h and zero h<r<R, right? Other velocity component can be set to v(0,r)=0.
At the symmetric boundary (bottom edge of the rectangle) the change of v with respect to r delv/delr at r=0 can be set to 0 and it makes sense to me but what should be the other boundary condition on w at the symmetry boundary? w(z,0)=0 seems not logical.
Thanks for any help in advance.

You also need radial velocity v=0 on r=0. A non-zero value would mean there is a source/sink of mass on the symmetry axis.

It would be a useful addition to show a picture of "the rectangle" in $r,z$ space and how the jet is located within it.
